# Why std::function<boost::any ()> won't work in this situation?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I faced a situation where I want this kind of function:

```
MoveOnly createMoveOnly();
```

Stored here:

```
std::function<boost::any ()> factory = &createMoveOnly;
```

This should work, AFAIK, because `MoveOnly` is convertible to `boost::any`

Using boost 1.55 which supports move semantics for boost.any, it does not work. It triggers an error about trying to use the deleted copy constructor for `MoveOnly`internally in the holder for `boost::any`. But the top-level constructor for Boost.Any is correctly chosen (It uses a templated ValueType && that forwards parameters).

Maybe the problem is in `std::function`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that `boost::any` requires a copy constructor and assignment operator.  The documentation seems to indicate this:

> As the emphasis of a value lies in its state not its identity, values can be copied and typically assigned one to another, *requiring the explicit or implicit definition of a public copy constructor and public assignment operator.* Values typically live within other scopes, i.e. within objects or blocks, rather than on the heap. Values are therefore normally passed around and manipulated directly as variables or through references, but not as pointers that emphasize identity and indirection.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any/reference.html

Comment: +1 [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/any.html) — A class whose instances can hold instances of any type that satisfies [ValueType](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/any/reference.html#any.ValueType) requirements.

Comment: In practice, `boost::any` stores a type erased wrapper around the stored object with copy operations in it, which would fail to compile for your `MoveOnly`.

Comment: So I cannot use boost::any for move-only types? I will have to make my own type-erased class then.

Comment: You can, but you'll have to proxy it or use a flyweight pattern so that it's stored in something that CAN be copied.  Maybe std::weak_ptr?

Comment: @Brad yes, but that is a dirty workaround I guess. I think I will have to code a type-erased, movable-only class.

Comment: I wonder why this restriction is applied. Wouldn't boost::any be more useful if it allowed move-only types? Or would this create any other problems?

Comment: It might, but it would also have serious drawbacks.  If I have the stipulation that some types in a generic container are move only and some are not, then to meet the contract for all types, I must assume that NONE of them can be assigned or copied, ever.  My guess is that the Boost team decided that more often than not, users would want to use types that were assignable, and would rather not have to jump through hoops in that case to do things like `x = y;` or passing arguments by value.

Comment: @GermánDiago Then `boost::any` itself would not itself be copyable, so it would be something else altogether. Note that Boost.TypeErasure can help you define your own type-erasing holder.

Comment: @Luc Danton. Last time I took a look I could not.figure out how to use move only classes.

Comment: @GermánDiago You’re absolutely right, my recommendation was knee-jerk from glancing over the words ‘type erasure’. The library is not quite there yet.